# Multi part line cannot be bound

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net

I am creating a program in `VB.net` and in one form.
I want to show the data of 2 tables in one Data grid view but it says that multi part cannot be found.
Here is what I have tried so far

```
sql = "select EntryNo.Student_Info, firstName.Student_Info, 
lastName.Student_Info, gender.Student_Info, Height.First_WeightIn, 
Weight.First_WeightIn, BMI.First_WeightIn, NutriStat.First_WeightIn from 
Student_Info full Join First_WeightIn on EntryNo.Student_Info = 
EntryNo.First_WeightIn"
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a " missing at the end of your sql statement

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You started a " at the beginning of your query but forgot to close it

Comment: oh yeah i just forgot to type that

Comment: can you tell me the name of your schema

Comment: Are you pointing to the right database or table?

Comment: "EntryNo" is not one of the tables in the FROM clause.

Comment: Your query is all wrong... You are using the column names as the table and the table names as the columns... Flip them around. For example `SELECT Student_Info.EntryNo, Student_Info.firstName etc`...

Comment: Codexer thank you soooo muchhh

Comment: @Jhaze please see my answer and you are welcome!

Comment: @Codexer unfortunately im at bed right now but my coleague just  confirmed your answer. Thanks again. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments you are using the column names as the table and the table names as the columns...

It should be `[TableName/Alias].[ColumnName]`. Also worth mentioning `Weight` is a reserved keyword in SSMS, you should wrap the column in `[ ]`...

*Please *make sure you include your schema as well*, for example `dbo` or what ever schema you are using. For example `FROM dbo.Student_Info si`...

```
SELECT si.EntryNo,
       si.firstName,
       si.lastName,
       si.gender,
       wi.Height,
       wi.[Weight], --reserved keyword in SSMS
       wi.BMI,
       wi.NutriStat
FROM Student_Info si
     FULL JOIN First_WeightIn wi ON wi.EntryNo = si.EntryNo;
```